# Can't add field that begins with an underscore in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, fields

There's a field in a FoxPro table that I'm trying to pull in a Crystal Report (v10), and it begins with an `_` and it doesn't appear in `Field Explorer->Fields->Database Fields-><table-name>->_fieldName`

Are fields that start with `_` invisible to Crystal Reports?

Comment: in the MS world, _ as a preface is commonly used to hide functions, methods, etc.  I wouldn't be surprised if that is the case here.